# alfresco java dictionary service

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

Hello i have one simple question i guess.
I need to use DictionaryService dictionaryService in my code more specific i need this:
`this.dictionaryService.getAspect(VykazModel.qProps);` to work all what i get is a null pointer exception so i understand that i have to define somewhere dictionaryService but i dont know how and what value i suppose to set.

I found this http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/dictionary/DictionaryService.html but it still dont tell me how can i set dictionaryService in order to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject it in your bean as simple as [this](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/afde3f58f91567b6f7eaa0bbac5e5adc38087fe0/projects/remote-api/source/test-resources/alfresco/declarative-spreadsheet-webscript-application-context.xml#L11) :

> ```
>    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
>     <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
>
>     <beans>
>        <import resource="classpath:alfresco/application-context.xml"/>
>        <import resource="classpath:alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml"/>
>
>        <bean id="webscript.org.alfresco.repository.test.declarativeSpreadsheetWebScript.get"
>              class="org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.TestDeclarativeSpreadsheetWebScriptGet"
>              parent="declarativeSpreadsheetWebScript">
>              <property name="dictionaryService" ref="DictionaryService"/>
>        </bean>
>
>     </beans>
> ```